# Replacement for damaged Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

I got a Motherboard of a Notebook that has three identical capacitor damaged. But I can't find this model, I think its a smd electrolytic 390uF 2.5v. But its so hard to find one that match with that specifications.

Can someone confirm that? Or just tell me what is the Real Model of it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like OS-CON or a copy of it. 2.5 V and 390 uF just like you said. If you can’t find an exact replacement, you can always go higher in voltage rating.

Answer (score 2):

It's a low-impedance SMT capacitor, likely a polymer type. Here's results from a parametric search at Digikey with some manufacturer part numbers. Note the ESR numbers (circled), usually lower is better, but they are all pretty low, so any of them will probably work fine. All are 105°C types, and rated ripple currents are similar.

You might also want to consider size, especially height, in a notebook, but they are all 6mm or a bit less.

[image]